# document.currentScript is Null (not in callback/async)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

So hopefully someone can shed some light on this.  I've been trying unsuccessfully to get document.currentScript to work.  Finally just as a simple test to make sure it was working correctly, I put together this sanity test...

```
<script>
    scriptNode = document.currentScript;
    console.log('Script Node');
    console.log(scriptNode);
</script>
```

...only for it to fail as well.  The second console.log showed null.
I also logged the document element at the same point to look at it's members in case I was misspelling/capitalizing something, but currentScript was there, but still null.

The only thing I can think of is that this is occurring because this element is being loaded into a modal, and so because it's not being loaded initially, the value isn't being set, but I can't find any documentation saying it should behave that way.

If I'm missing something please let me know.

EDIT:  Just to note, I also tried import.meta but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Where or how is this code being run, more specifically, what browser/environment are you using to test this? Is this in a local/remote file? Using your same code do you see working results on code editors like CodePen or jsfiddle? The code works as intended for me on those sites and running to code locally, so there is some factor that is causing it to fail for you that is likely related to how/where you are running this code.

Comment: Please post a reproducable code sample or try to reproduce it in a js fiddle

Comment: I've tested this in both the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox and get the same result.  As I mentioned in the post, html page this script is in is being loaded dynamically after the page loads, so is that what you 3 tested?